# How to get the intersection of lists while handling duplicates without bias?

Tags: haskell

My explanation in the title might have been fairly bad, but the problem I'm having is this:

```
shared [[10,5,10,10,7,10],[2,6,10,10]]
output: [10,10,10,10]
```

I want the output to be [10,10].

I'm trying to write a variation of [`Data.List.intersect`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/8.8.3/docs/html/libraries/base-4.13.0.0/Data-List.html#v:intersect) which is unbiased with respect with the order of the arguments. Each value should appear in the result the same number of times in whichever list it occurs fewer times. (In contrast, with `Data.List.intersect` if a value shows up in the result the amount of occurrences of it will be the same as in the first list.)

My current attempt is:

```
import Data.List
myintersect :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
myintersect [] _ = []
myintersect (x:xs) ys
    | x `elem` ys = x : myintersect xs ys
    | otherwise = myintersect xs ys

shared :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [a]
shared x = foldr1 myintersect x
```

It doesn't work correctly, though. `shared [[10,5,10,10,7,10],[2,6,10,10]]` is `[10,10,10,10]`, rather than `[10,10]`.

I've been looking into using `zip`, but that fails to work with different length lists.

Comment: How about just `nub` the result at the end?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I want duplicates to be there, but only the same amount of duplicates that appear in both lists.

Comment: Checking if I understood your requirements: if the inputs are `[2,6,10,10]` and `[10,10,5,7,10]`, is the output supposed to be `[]`?

Comment: @duplode I think what OP wants is to count the shared elements between two lists, but counting the elements only once each, so that they have to "pair up" between the lists.

Comment: @MikaelF To me, the `zipWith` idea at the end suggests that, in the title, "common items" and "same amount" should be read as "items at the same position" and "equal value", respectively, but I'm not fully sure.

Comment: @duplode Sorry for my misleading idea at the end there, I was just trying nearly anything I could think of. MikaelF is correct about what I'm looking for. I want the shared items from both lists with the same amount from both lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you sort the lists first and then traverse them side by side:

```
shared xs ys = go xs' ys' where
  go [] _ = []
  go _ [] = []
  go aas@(a:as) bbs@(b:bs) = case compare a b of
    GT -> go aas bs
    EQ -> a : go as bs
    LT -> go as bbs
  xs' = sort xs
  ys' = sort ys
```

As @WillNess pointed out in the comments, `Data.List.Ordered` has [just the function you want](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:isect):

```
isect :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
-- |  The 'isect' function computes the intersection of two ordered lists.
-- An element occurs in the output as many times as the minimum number of
-- occurrences in either input.  If either input is a set,  then the output
-- is a set.
--
-- > isect [ 1,2, 3,4 ] [ 3,4, 5,6 ]   == [ 3,4 ]
-- > isect [ 1, 2,2,2 ] [ 1,1,1, 2,2 ] == [ 1, 2,2 ]
```

Since functions from `Data.List.Ordered` assume that input lists are sorted, you have to [sort](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort) them [first](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on):

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List     (sort)

bettershared = Data.List.Ordered.isect `on` sort
```

Comment: It seems the `zip`-based `shared` can unduly drop elements. For instance, `shared [10,5,10,10,7,10] [2,6,10,10,7] = [10,10,10]`. `bettershared` looks fine as far as that goes.

Comment: @duplode Thank you, you're right, this is because the zip ended up looking something like `[(10,10),(10,10),(7,10)]`, mixing "real" duplicates with ones that had already been paired up. I took out that part of my answer.

Comment: your complexity is off. consider `[[1,2,100],[99,98..2]]`. both lists will be forced through in full after being sorted. (unless you consider `[2..99]` "shorter" than `[1,2,100]` )

Comment: also, [``bettershared = Data.List.Ordered.isect `Data.Function.on` Data.List.sort``](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:isect). (cc @duplode)

Comment: @WillNess I had assumed `sort` was lazy, but apparently it can't be completely lazy for all inputs; I took that off my answer. As for `isect`, this should definitely be the accepted answer.

Comment: `sort` *is* lazy, but `go` forces both lists through, in the worst case. of course in case `[[1..10],[90,80..20]]`, it only forces the one head element of the second sorted list.

Comment: @WillNess Nice find. The second sentence in the docs' description of `isect` is perhaps the clearest way to explain what the OP wants here.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map a Int` to represent a bag (AKA multiset) of values of type `a`. Elements of the multiset are keys in the map, and they're paired with their counts.

```
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

-- Add a value to a bag.
addElem :: Ord a => a -> Map a Int -> Map a Int
addElem = M.alter $ \mc ->
  case mc of
    -- The item is not in the bag. Add it with count 1
    Nothing -> Just 1
    -- The item is in the bag. Increment its count.
    Just count -> Just (count + 1)

-- Build a bag from a list.
buildBag :: Ord a => [a] -> Map a Int
buildBag = foldl' (flip addElem) M.empty

-- Remove one copy of a value from a bag if it's there. Otherwise, return Nothing.
removeElem :: Ord a => a -> Map a Int -> Maybe (Map a Int)
removeElem = M.alterF $ \mc ->
  case mc of
    -- The item is not in the bag. Return Nothing.
    Nothing -> Nothing
    -- The item is in the bag with count 1. Delete it.
    Just 1 -> Just Nothing
    -- At least two of the item are in the bag. Decrement the count.
    Just count -> Just (Just (count - 1))

-- Intersect a list with a bag.
isectWithBag :: Ord a => [a] -> Map a Int -> [a]
isectWithBag [] _b = []
isectWithBag (x:xs) b = case removeElem x b of
      Nothing -> isectWithBag xs b
      Just b' -> x : isectWithBag xs b'

-- Intersect a list with a list.
isect :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
isect xs ys = isectWithBag xs (buildBag ys)
```

`isect xs ys` takes time

```
O((|xs|+|ys|) log |nub ys|)
```

So when you have information about what the lists are likely to look like, it's best to choose `ys` to be the one with the fewest *distinct* elements.

---

The above solution is disappointing in two ways:

1. It's completely strict in the contents of the second list.
2. To get optimal performance requires that we guess correctly which list has more distinct elements.

It turns out that we can solve both problems at once. We'll work through both lists "in parallel", producing values whenever possible along the way. We use the same bag representation as before, with the same `addElem`, `removeElem`, and `isectWithBag`. In this case, we use two bags, with the elements still available for matching from `xs`, and from `ys`, as we move along the two lists. We maintain the invariant that the `Map` representing the first bag is no larger than the `Map` representing the second bag, and in particular that it has 0 or 1 fewer keys. We do this by swapping the bags and lists as necessary.

```
isect2 :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
isect2 = go M.empty M.empty
  where
    go xb _yb [] ys = isectWithBag ys xb
    go xb yb (x:xs) ys =
      case removeElem x yb of
        Nothing -> go' (insertElem x xb) yb xs ys
        Just yb' -> x : go' xb yb' xs ys

    go' xb yb xs ys
      | M.size xb <= M.size yb
      = go xb yb xs ys
      | otherwise
      = go yb xb ys xs
```

The worst case performance occurs when the intersection is empty. In this case, we get

```
O((|xs|+|ys|) (log (min (|nub xs|, |nub ys|))))
```

---

Unfortunately, the "improved" solution has a problem: when removal from the bag fails, we have to insert into a similarly-sized bag. This means a failure costs twice as much as a success, so this solution will be *slower* than the monolithic one unless the numbers of distinct elements in the two lists are extremely different from each other. Can we fix this? Yes! We currently maintain two bags with the invariant that their intersection is empty. We can take advantage of this by using a different representation that uses *one* `Map` for both. This will make "success" a constant term slower, but "failure" almost twice as fast! We can indicate the number of copies in the `xs` bag by a *positive* count, and the number of `ys` by a *negative* count. We'll keep track of the number of `Map` entries with positive values and/or negative values separately. Unfortunately, I have yet to find a non-horrible way to express this version of the algorithm.

Comment: this would entail the `(...(({a}-b)-c)-d...)` linear fold structure for the `[a,b,c,d,...]` input (as hinted / shown at the top of the question), not the potentially tree-shaped `{a} ^ {b} ^ {c} ^ {d} ^ ...` fold structure.  which one of the two shapes is advantageous here depends on the degree of similarity between all those lists, of course. so in some cases the linear fold structure can be better. ---- also, as is usual in these cases, naturally we all assumed `Ord` constraint but the OP mentions `Eq`. :)

Comment: @WillNess, I don't understand what you mean about a tree-shaped structure. It would be possible to work through the lists in a more "parallel" order, looking back and forth using two `Map`s, but that produces somewhat oddly-shaped results with more complexity and no definite advantage. Maybe explain more in your own answer? `Eq` is far too boring, so whatever.

Comment: [`Data.List.Ordered.foldt'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:foldt-39-). I [mention it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646408/getting-a-list-of-common-items-with-the-same-amount-in-each-from-two-lists-has/60659501?noredirect=1#comment107309792_60648850) in a comment above yours, thought you saw it. (agree on `Eq` of course)

Comment: it's  also [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold#Tree-like_folds). my intuition about its advantages is informed by various [primes](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Tree_merging) [algorithms](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Linear_merging).

Comment: @WillNess, I still don't understand what you're getting at. Could you please explain both the motivation and the technique in your own answer rather than as comments on this one?

Comment: I'll think about it some more, will see if it amounts to an answer.

Comment: Pretty slick. I couldn't understand the "unmatched elements" wording; I'd put it differently, as e.g. "we use two bags, with the elements still available for matching from `xs`, and from `ys`, as we move along the two lists" - something like that.

Comment: @WillNess, it's going to get a lot slicker tonight. I'll let you know once I write out another two steps of improvements.

Answer (score 0):

When sorting seems to be a reasonable approach in the first place, most of the time it turns out that it is infact not. Sorting has always been my very last resort.

So in this very particular case, which can also be extended to unlimited number of lists, my approach would be folding the `shared` list `[[2,6,10,10],[10,5,10,10,7,10]]` on to a `Map` data structure.

I will give only the algorithm at the moment and later, once i have more time the code will follow.

1. First pass of `foldr` the Map becomes;

   `{ 5 : [1], 7 : [1], 10: [4]}`
2. Second pass of `foldr` the Map becomes;

   `{ 2 :[1], 5 :[1], 6 :[1], 7 :[1], 10:[2,4]}`
3. Once folding phase is over, just analyze the Map. Filter out the Map keys with values those have the same length with `shared` list, which in this case happens to be only key `10`.
4. Take the minimum of the value `[2,4]` which is `2` and do like `replicate 2 10` to compose the result.

So as promised here is my take with the `Map`;

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

isect :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
isect xss = solve $ mapper xss 1 M.empty
            where
            mapper :: Ord a => [[a]] -> Int -> M.Map a ([Int], Int) -> M.Map a ([Int], Int)
            mapper [] _ m       = m
            mapper (xs:xss) i m = mapper xss (i+1) currentMap
                                  where
                                  currentMap = foldr renew m xs
                                  renew x m' = M.alter f x m'
                                               where
                                               f (Just ((n:ns),j)) = case i - j of
                                                                     0 -> Just ((n+1):ns,j)
                                                                     1 -> Just (1:n:ns,i)
                                                                     _ -> Nothing
                                               f Nothing           = case i of
                                                                     1 -> Just ([1],i)
                                                                     _ -> Nothing
            len = length xss

            solve :: M.Map a ([Int], Int) -> [a]
            solve = M.foldMapWithKey toList
                    where
                    toList k (ns,i) | i == len  = replicate (minimum ns) k
                                    | otherwise = mempty
```

where it does it's job pretty well and *perhaps* slightly faster than `sort`ing but honestly as suggested by @WillNess, it seems to me that i would/should rather simply do it like

```
import qualified Data.List.Ordered as DLO

isect1 :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
isect1 = foldr1 shared
         where
         shared xs ys = DLO.isect (sort xs) (sort ys)
```

which seems to use half as much the memory footprint of the `Map` method without any significant performance penalty.

Comment: this won't work. how would your function know whether to increment the count, or to add another element into the list of counts like you show? instead, convert each list into Map getting a list of Maps, and then join/intersect the Maps. will work for any number of lists, and the Maps under join/intersect are even Semigroup, so could use tree-shaped fold a-la `Data.List.Ordered.foldt'` to process this list. the one resulting Map will need one more obvious post-processing step. so, `[[10,6,10,10,7,10],[2,6,10,10]] --> [[(10,4),(6,1),(7,1)],[(2,1),(6,1),(10,2)]] --> [(10,2),(6,1)] --> [10,10,6]`.

Comment: @Will Ness I was expecting you... This is just a pseudo code... I can always implement something around this and i will. Yet what you are suggesting is also nice and possible of course... The moral of this answer is to show how `sort` is wastefull in some cases where people consider using it reasonable.

Comment: I think `sort` is perfectly fine here; building a Map is equivalent to sorting. :) without either of the two you'll end up with quadratic behavior.  btw see my comment under the other answer.

Comment: @Will Ness yes but with a clever implementation, once you are done with the Map you are *almost* done with the job.

Comment: after you're done with the sort in O(n log n), all's left is the asymptotically insignificant O(n) scan over the sorted lists. it's the same thing really - sorted list is the Map's fringe.

Comment: @Will Ness A clever code with Map has the opportunity to cut many redundant steps but it can be best acknowledged when i have a code to show. i.e. Second pass would not look like as i show in the above pesudo code... `sort`ing and `isect` is a good hardwire but doesnt leave you with any playground.

Comment: The natural structure seems to be a bag, which can be represented as a `Map` but is conceptually different. Insert all elements of one list into the bag. Then for each element of the other list, check if the element is in the bag, and if so, remove one copy of it.